# Rotating array differently

Tags: java, matrix, 2d

hey,
I need to rotate a 2d array in such way :
4X4-->

```
Input      Output
1 2 3 4   5 1 2 3 
5 6 7 8   1 2 6 4 
1 2 3 4   5 3 7 8
5 6 7 8   6 7 8 4
```

or for odd 5X5-->

```
Input            Output
1 2 3 4  5   6 1 2 3  4
6 7 8 9 10   1 2 7 8  5 
1 2 3 4  5   6 7 3 9 10
6 7 8 9 10   1 8 9 4  5
1 2 3 4  5   2 3 4 5 10
```

can someone help me?
as you can see there are two different rings and are gettin rotated .

plz help

Im out of ideas and luck.

Comment: What ideas have you come up with that you decided won't work?  What are the constraints on the problem?  Are you using Java or C++?

Comment: I'm using Java. language is not barrier.

Comment: Im not able to see how this can be implemented

Comment: you need to be a little more expressive. Please share your idea, what did you think about the solution? Just posting a question won't get you an answer. Or else you will keep getting downvotes and the question will be closed.

Comment: What code?  Is this homework?

Comment: @user484860.  Plot out all the X/Y values (before AND after) by hand once, and see if a pattern emerges.  BTW, there could be more than 2 rings.  For example, in a 6x6 array.

Comment: Is this homework by any chance? It's a simple algorithmics question.

Comment: How did you arrive at the expected output given each of the inputs?  If you walk through that process, one step at a time, and write out each step on a piece of paper, you will probably see a pattern and you can use that to develop an algorithm.

Comment: @merlyn yes thr will be more rings as size of array increases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the `n x n` array like this:

```
+-----------+
|\         /|
| \   1   / |
|  \     /  |
|   \   /   |
|    \ /    |
| 4   +   2 |
|    / \    |
|   /   \   |
|  /     \  |
| /   3   \ |
|/         \|
+-----------+
```

Then all pixels in region 1 move right one pixel, all pixels in region 2 move down one pixel, etc.

The regions can be defined mathematically.  Assume the lower-left corner is (0,0), then the line dividing regions 1&4 from 2&3 is `x = y`, and the line dividing regions 1&2 from 3&4 is `x = n - y`.  Then:

A pixel is in region 1 if `x < y` and `x > n - y`. (left of `x=y`, right of `x=n-y`)

A pixel is in region 2 if `x > y` and `x > n - y`. (right of `x=y`, right of `x=n-y`)

Similarly for regions 3 & 4.

You need to get the edge pixels right (some of those comparisons need an equal sign), and your code will depend on the odd-or-even-ness of the array size.  But you should be able to go from there.

Comment: can u guide me how can i implement your concept in form of array? are these right ?

Comment: //A pixel is in region 1 if x < y and x > n - y. (left of x=y, right of x=n-y)
       //A pixel is in region 2 if x > y and x > n - y. (right of x=y, right of x=n-y)
       //A pixel is in region 3 if x > y and x < n - y. (right of x=y, left of x=n-y)
       //A pixel is in region 4 if x < y and x < n - y. (left of x=y, left of x=n-y)

Comment: ive successfully implemented your logic. and divided array in 4 parts in JAVA. will now try to rotate them. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
int [][] size = new int[sx][sx];
int [][] rot = new int[sx][sx];
int x=0;
for(int i=0;i<sx;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<sx;j++)
    {
        size[i][j]=x++;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<sx;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<sx;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(size[i][j]+"\t");
    }
     System.out.println();
```

}

int n=sx-1;
  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {

```
    if(i<j && i>=n-j)
        rot[i+1][j]=size[i][j];

    else if(i>=j && i > n-j)
        rot[i][j-1]=size[i][j];

    else if(i>j && i <= n-j)

        rot[i-1][j]=size[i][j];

    else if(i<=j && i < n-j)
        rot[i][j+1]=size[i][j];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about going like this:

```
FIND OUTER EDGES (Hint: 0,0 to max_x,0; max_x,0 to max_x,max_y; max_x,max_y to 0,max_y; 0,max_y to 0,0)
Create a new array (call it buffer). (buffer[x][y])
buffer[1][0]=arr[0][0];
buffer[1][0]=arr[0][0];
buffer[1][0]=arr[0][0];
...
buffer[max_x][0]=arr[max_x - 1][0];
```

Make the next inner an "outer edge", start at 1,1 to max_x-1,max_y-1, and repeat.